# Import from parent directory failed with ImportError

Tags: python

I'm busy developing an application in python, my application is structured as follows

```
main.py
pr/
    core/
        __init__.py
        predictor.py
    gui/
        predictor/
            __init__.py
            predict_panel.py
        __init__.py
        pr_app.py
    __init__.py
```

I launch the application using `main.py`

inside `pr_app.py` I've got

```
class PrApp(wx.App):
    PREDICTOR = Predictor()
```

inside `predict_panel.py` I can successfully do

`from pr.core.predictor import Predictor`

but for some reason I cannot do

`from pr.gui.pr_app import PrApp`

I get presented with

`ImportError: cannot import name PrApp`

Is there some kind of gotcha when importing from parent directories in python, or am I missing something?

Comment: I thought the extra info was helpful.  @erikb85

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this and made a tree like yours, but with the addition of an `__init__.py` in the `pr` directory. Without that `__init__.py` your `from pr.core.predictor import Predictor` should fail, so I think you have it, but forgot to write it in your question.

I was not able to get the failure you did, it worked fine for me. I can do both imports from `predict_panel.py`, as I expected to.

However, if I from `pr_app.py` import `predict_panel`, then the import from `predict_panel.py` of `PrApp` will fail. This is because I have a circular import. You try to import `predict_panel` from `PrApp` during the import of `PrApp` and you try to import `PrApp` during the import of `predict_panel`. That would create an infinite recursion of imports, so it is not allowed.

The best way to solve this is to reorganize your code so you don't have to do circular imports. If `PrApp` imports `predict_panel`, why would `predict_panel` need `PrApp`? That's a sign of a flawed design.

However, the quickest way to fix it is to move one of the imports from the top of the module into the function/method where it's called. That's bad practice, but it will fix your problem quickly.

Comment: I've changed the layout a little bit to prevent circular import and it's working, the reason I needed to import PrApp was to access a constant I defined in there. I've moved the constant into a new file `settings.py` and life is good again. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I launch the application using main.py

By doing that you correctly make your `pr/` folder a package, so cross-referencing imports within that package should work. So both `pr.gui.pr_app import PrApp` and `from ..pr_app import PrApp` should work.

I think the problem in your case is that you haven’t made `pr` a real package. Try adding a `__init__.py` there too and it should work.

Comment: Then `from pr.core.predictor import Predictor` should not work either, so I think there is an `__init__.py` but he forgot to print it.

Comment: Bleh :( But well, then it should work, modifying the import path should not be necessary. Are the `__init__.py`s empty?

Answer (score -1):

The reason for not being able to import from your parent directory is that each script considers itself as top it's import tree. The only other things it looks at is the `sys.path`. So as far as I know your only chance to import *from above* is to add the parent directory to your path (absolute not relative).

Put this at the top of your file:

```
import sys
import os
import inspect

#enable imports from dir above
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(
    os.path.dirname(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))+"/.."))
```

Comment: Why not just `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/..")`

Comment: Not using `__file__` will get you around [problems like this](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15631), because this variable doesn't always exist.

Comment: Adding this before my import I can see the parent directory is being added to `sys.path`, although `from pr.gui.pr_app import PrApp` still produces the same error

Comment: If this was the problem, then his first import would also not work. And even *if* pr not being a proper module and on sys.path was the problem, it's quite an ugly hack to solve it. It would be better to make it a proper module.

Comment: It's just an answer to the question. Sorry that the question wasn't `please debug my code`

Comment: That's always the question here. :-)